# Add a class to a specific element and not to all that have the same class

Tags: jquery

My problem must be very simple to solve for many of you but I have no idea how to specify the element, here's what's going on.

I have a list of products with their images and an *Add To Cart* button for each product. I want to add a class to the product's container when its specific Add To Cart button has been clicked.

So far I'm able to do it but all products' containers get the class added.

Here's my basic HTML:

```
<div class="prod-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
<div class="product-info"><span class="price">$40.00</span>
  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
  <a href="#" class="add"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a>
</div>

<div class="prod-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-2.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
<div class="product-info"><span class="price">$40.00</span>
  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
  <a href="#" class="add"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a>
</div>

<div class="prod-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-3.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
<div class="product-info"><span class="price">$40.00</span>
  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
  <a href="#" class="add"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith('<img src="images/button-added-to-cart.png" alt="Item added to Cart" class="added">');
  $('.prod-img').addClass('prod-added');
return false;
});
```

Just FYI, once the Add To Cart button is clicked it gets replaced with an "Item Added to Cart" image.

How can I make the specific product's container get a class ('prod-added') to it without adding it to the rest of the products?

Thanks for any help on this.

--

**EDIT**

I apologize, I did not expect the solution to be based on actually selecting exactly the previous element. I do have two more elements in between the product and the Add to Cart button. Code has been updated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your edit, it looks like you want the matching div that is right before the parent of `this`:

```
$('.add').click(function(){

    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="images/button-added-to-cart.png" alt="Item added to Cart" class="added">');
    $(this).parent().prev('.prod-img').addClass('prod-added');
    return false;
});
```

More generally, you want a way to link the clicked link to the target div.  The above approach is somewhat fragile, as it is dependent on your HTML being arranged in just the right way.  A better approach might be to put each set of elements into a container, and reference them that way:

```
<div class="product-display"> 
   <div class="prod-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
   <div class="product-info"><span class="price">$40.00</span>
     <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
     <a href="#" class="add"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="product-display">     
   <div class="prod-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-2.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
   <div class="product-info"><span class="price">$40.00</span>
     <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
     <a href="#" class="add"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then the key line in your jquery becomes

```
 $(this).parents(".product-display").find('.prod-img').addClass('prod-added');
```

Now it doesn't matter if you change the order of elements within a "product-display" group, or add new items in between them, or anything like that.

Comment: JacobM, I had to edit the code above, as I told Loktar below, I never thought the solutions was dependent exactly on the previous element. Thanks for your help as well.

Comment: Edited to reflect change to HTML, and also to provide a more generalized solution.

Comment: JacobM, I like your solution better, it's more scalable. I do have my elements wrapped in a container but it's not a DIV but an LI inside an OL list with the class of 'search-results', so what I did was: -- $(this).parents("ol.search-results li").find('.prod-img').addClass('prod-added'); -- and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

For it to work you will have to do this

```
$('.add').click(function(){
     $(this).parent('div').prev('.prod-img').addClass('prod-added');
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="images/button-added-to-cart.png" alt="Item added to Cart" class="added">');

    return false;
});
```

Almost the same as JacobM, but since you are replacing the element in the dom you have to apply the class before that.

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/eTWkA/1/

Comment: Loktar, I had to edit my code above, I never thought the solution was dependent exactly on the previous element. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok updated my answer, try that and see if it works, also updated the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Perfect! It worked exactly as I needed it. Thanks a lot Loktar. I do have a question though: You used .parent(), but aren't <div class="prod-img"> and <div class="product-info"> siblings since they are at the same 'level'?... In other words, how is <div class="prod-img"> the parent of <div class="product-info">? Not sure if I'm asking the right thing, I'm very new to jQuery as you can see. Thanks.

Comment: .add is contained in product info, so this.parent = product-info, and prod-image comes right before product-info so its the previous element. Basically your starting from the .add level and working your way up to change its style, if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh! Ok, I think I got it :). We're looking for the parent of the Add to Cart button which is <div class="product-info">, and then we look for the previous element of that div and change it, right? ^_^ -- Ok, just read your explanation, yes, it makes sense now, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Loktar and JacobM.

The solution to this is:

**HTML:**

```
<ol class="search-results">
  <li>
    <div class="prod-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="product-info"><span class="price">$40.00</span>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
      <a href="#" class="add"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a> </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="prod-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-2.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="product-info"><span class="price">$40.00</span>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
      <a href="#" class="add"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a> </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="prod-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-3.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="product-info"><span class="price">$40.00</span>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
      <a href="#" class="add"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a> </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    $(this).parents("ol.search-results li").find('.prod-img').addClass('prod-added');
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="images/button-added-to-cart.png" alt="Item added to Cart" class="added">');          
return false;
});
```

So when you click the 'Add to Cart' button, not only the button gets replaced with an 'Item Added to Cart' image, but the image of the product gets a class added to it that you can then style in your CSS to improve usability of the Add to Cart feature.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the best way to do that is specify an id to each element
and do that:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="images/button-added-to-cart.png" alt="Item added to Cart" class="added">');
    $('#' + id).addClass('prod-added');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: How do you know which ID you want?

Comment: Even if he changed his example to have the id's you require, you can't use the same id for multiple elements in html.  It is strictly forbidden.  So then it gets crazy.  You need special prefixes for each element and then you have to parse and other craziness.  `.prev()` is much simpler.

Comment: This isn't necessary. It can be done using relative navigation of the elements.